# Priority issue in Sitemaps

Tags: python, django, sitemap

I am trying to use Django sitemaps.

```
class BlogSiteMap(Sitemap):
    """A simple class to get sitemaps for blog"""

    changefreq = 'hourly'
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Blog.objects.order_by('-pubDate')

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.pubDate
```

My problem is..I wanted to set the priority of first 3 blog object as 1.0 and rest of them
as 0.5 priority.

I read the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#ref-contrib-sitemaps) but couldn't any way out of it.

Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can alter each object with its priority. Like that for example:

```
def items(self):
    for i, obj in enumerate(Blog.objects.order_by('-pubDate')):
       obj.priority = i < 3 and 1 or 0.5
       yield obj

def priority(self, obj):
    return obj.priority
```

Comment: I have the same problem but a little bit different:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172520/how-to-have-different-change-frequency-and-priority-for-a-list-of-items-in-djang

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might work:

```
def priority(self, obj):
    if obj.id in list(Blog.objects.all()[:3].values_list('id'))
        return 1.0
    else:
        return 0.5
```